# Ubuntu 13.04 Unable to locate package package-name

Tags: 13.04, apt

I was using Ubuntu 12.04. But today I just made format my system and installed Ubuntu 13.04. I have made copied the archive file (`/var/cache/apt/archives`) from Ubuntu 12.04 and made paste to 13.04 . After I made the system update by doing commands (`sudo apt-get update`) terminal. Then after that whatever I am trying to install on my system it is showing error like

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package package-name
```

Even I tried to install apache server by using `sudo apt-get apache2`. It is showing the error like

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apache2
```

So can someone kindly tell me how to solve this issue. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: 13.04 is EOL, you need to upgrade to 14.04.1

Comment: I want to use 13.04. So is there any suggestions to fix the issue?

Comment: see @EliahKagan linked question - note this will just make the repos work, you will likely not receive any more updates as raring is unsupported

Comment: any one here to solve my problem. I really need it.

Comment: We have given you a link. 13.04 is unsupported, and there is no reason not to upgrade, other than convenience. http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release is the best you can get, but you still won't get updates - your computer will be vulnerable. Why do you want to keep using it?